# Async Firestore Function Crashes App in HTML

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, angularfire2

I have a function like that:

```
  async profilePhoto(id) {
    const docRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.colRef.doc(id);
    const promise = await docRef.ref.get();
    const photoUrl = await promise.get('photoURL');
    console.log(photoUrl);
    return photoUrl;
  }
```

I can call it from .ts file like

```
this.userService.profilePhoto('userId123');
```

and it works well. Logs the the url.

But when i try to call it in HTML like

```
<img [src]="userService.profilePhoto('userId123')" />
```

App crashes. Browser frozen. Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `const promise = await docRef.get();` instead of `const promise = await docRef.ref.get();`? See https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/9e19b149f5613521f4b2167f584db34f294643e8/src/firestore/document/document.ts#L31

Comment: If the app crashes, certainly there is an error message describing what went wrong. Please edit the question to show all relevant information.

Comment: docRef.ref.get() works well as i said in .ts file. Problem was Html. I guess it's about async thing. Img tag was in an async ngFor loop. Because of crash i can not see any console message. :/